# How to remove commas from CSV file using Vi

Tags: csv, unix, sed, vi, text-processing

I have a file which is as follows:

```
98|N|N|N|N|S,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
99|N|N|N|N|S,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
100|N|N|N|N|S,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

How do I remove these extra commas from the end of each line.

I have about 10 files, with each file containing over 1 million rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
sed -i 's/,\+\r*$//' file
```

Comment: Thank you. After I ran the command, when I open the file, the commas are still there.

Comment: @chintans why? do you run the exact same command? have you changed the filename to your file or with -i?

Comment: I used the following: `sed -i 's/,\+$//' myfile.csv`. Then when I do `vi myfile.csv`, I still see the commas.

Comment: @chintans are there space between the last comma to the end?

Comment: Not sure, how do I find that out?

Comment: I also tried this `sed -n '/5628/s/,*\r*$//p' myfile.csv`. It prints exactly what I want but it does not save it.

Comment: @chintans with -i option to save it.